# How to make something asymetric with Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I have build a little text widget with HTML and CSS.
It looks good and as intended, but since I did not do it with FlexBox it gets depicted wrong on certain sites.
The "Place here" the icon and the "To the Job" are placed there by setting the position with hardcoding. The hardcoding makes the widget appear to small or long depending on the width of the document.
So I would want them to be flex. But I dont know how I would make a flex arrangement , that looks like this. Every text and and the Icon are different elements.
I have tried with flex but then there is too much of a white space gap between Job Title and Job description.
Thanks for your help and sorry for the stupid question.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a simple example:

First think about how you need to structure your HTML. What i see here is 1 big box with 3 childs in it. `Job Title Here` and `Description of the Job here` are the sub-childs of the first child element.

If you put `display: flex` on the big box, the childs gets aligned next to eatch other horizontally.

Now at this point it looks ugly, they stick together. To make them push away from eatch other set `justify-content: space-between`. It adds as much space between the childs as they can get inside the box.

Now we got the problem they are not vertically aligned. Here you need to set `align-items: center` this will center the childs inside the flexbox

```css
* {
   margin: 0; 
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid #dadada;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding:20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px lightgrey;
  margin: 10px;
}


h2 {
   color: darkorange;
}

#tojob {
   cursor: pointer;
   position: relative;
}
#tojob::before {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   width: 0;
   height: 2px;
   bottom: 0;
   background: darkorange;
   transition: width 200ms;
}

#tojob:hover::before {
     width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
   <div>
      <h2>Job title here</h2>
      <p>description here</p>
   </div>
   <p style="margin-left: auto">Place here</p>
   <p id="tojob" style="margin-left: 25%">to the job</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That looks promising You have helped me alot ! Thank you faruki & have a nice day !